# References for edge ideals (graph theory & commutative algebra)

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, commutative-algebra, binomial-ideals

I'm thinking of doing a project with some undergraduates soon involving edge ideals, particularly binomial edge ideals. Do you have a gentle introductory reference to this topic suitable for undergraduates?

We can assume that the students are comfortable with basic algebraic objects such as rings and ideals, as well as what graphs are and some of their basic theory.